# Javascript function not changing <pre> innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blender

So I have a simple setup going here where I load up a file (A blender .obj file) and display it. Then I call this function:

```
function parseFile(){
        var fileText = $('#file').html();
        var fileLine = fileText.split("\r\n");
        $('#file').html(fileLine[5]);
    }
```

Which should make it so it displays the 6th line of the file, but it still displays the whole file. How do I make it split the lines like they are in the actual file?

Edit: Just so everyone know's I'm loading the file like this: `$('#file').load('model.obj');`

Comment: Can you show us the content of fileText? Or the html of the pre#file?

Comment: Also, fileLine[5] is actually the 6th position.

Comment: Minor sidenote here, but `fileLine[5]` will show the 6th line not the 5th.

Comment: you're assuming the line delimiter is a LF \n (new line feed), while it could be a CR \r (carriage return). you're also assuming the obj file even has new lines in it. try opening the file in something like Notepad++ and navigating to View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters and see what it really is.

Comment: It's CRLF, so I've changed it to .split("\r\n");

Comment: And when do you execute `parseFile()`? After the load has finished? Try to `console.log(fileText)` and show us the results

Comment: It's saying No File (What I have the text in <pre> set to before the load.) But it is literally called right after the load. So what gives?

Comment: @CyanPrime check my answer it is possible the element is loaded yet and according to the jquery api if the element is not a part of the DOM it won't call the load function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous. The method will return, but the content will be available somewhen in the future. You'll need to use a callback:

```
$('#file').load('model.obj', function(response, status) {
    alert("Now the file is loaded");
    parseFile();
});
alert("Loading the file just began, nothing available by now");
```

Or more narrative, using the deferred interface:

```
$('#file').load('model.obj').then(parseFile);
```

If you need/want to parse the server response anyway, it might be a better to use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directly instead of loading it into a `innerHTML` and reading from there... You even could use a dedicated `dataFilter` for the blender.obj file type.

Comment: Not sure why I forgot about the asynchronous cal :( but this is most likely the problem.

Comment: Can you explain how I would use ajax? I tried var 
                fileText = $.ajax("model.obj");
  var fileLine = fileText.split(/\r\n/); but it now says .split() isn't a function

Comment: Though I got the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6338837/582295 your answer lead me to it, so you get the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is only a problem with '\n'

Try this :

```
var fileLine = fileText.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your call like this `$(parseFile());` and make sure your HTML actually contains an element with the id of file.