# JQuery issue with getting string from local file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338797/jquery-to-load-text-file-data) for getting string from text file but when I try to alert it, the pop up says "Data Loaded: undefined". I put my file to the root directory, but I don't know hot to use local host on my computer. I am testing it in dreamweaver and did not send any updates to the server. Which url I should use for local testing on my Mac computer to get string from file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get python(https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and install it. Then open a terminal and change to the directory that your html/text file is in and run `python3 -m http.server` which will start a very basic server (enough for your needs) on port 8000. Very easy!